# php regex identifying multiple patterns

Tags: php, regex

I am strugling to identify the regex for the following :

text :

```
VHHH 020218Z 0202/0306 20010KT 9999 FEW015 SCT025 TX32/0206Z TX32/0306Z TN27/0222Z TEMPO 0202/0209 2500 -TSRA SHRA FEW010CB SCT015 TEMPO 0215/0221 3500 SHRA FEW015CB SCT020 TEMPO 0221/0303 2500 -TSRA SHRA FEW010CB SCT015 TEMPO 0303/0306 3500 SHRA FEW015CB SCT020=
```

I want to get all the info after the word `TEMPO` but where it gets to the next `TEMPO` i.e. an array with all the instances

E.g. in this example

```
1: TEMPO 0202/0209 2500 -TSRA SHRA FEW010CB SCT015 
2: TEMPO 0215/0221 3500 SHRA FEW015CB SCT020 
3: TEMPO 0221/0303 2500 -TSRA SHRA FEW010CB SCT015 
4: TEMPO 0303/0306 3500 SHRA FEW015CB SCT020=
```

I have tried `"/TEMPO (.*?) TEMPO/"` and `"/TEMPO (.*)\Z/"` etc etc  but just can't crack it.

Comment: May I suggest you have a look at http://www.alexander-ott.com/phpmyeasyweather/ It's not 100% compatible with newer versions of PHP but it's quite easy to fix. It will handle most of the METAR and TAFs

Comment: Is that TAF made up or is that a real one? Visibility 10 km -> 2500 m in the same TAF. Don't think I have seen that before

Comment: Is none of the answers correct for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can try that:

```
TEMPO\s*\K.*?(?=(?:TEMPO|\s*$))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8bVN9H/4/)

Sample Code: ([Run here](http://ideone.com/QwlOqh))

```
<?php
$re = '/TEMPO\s*\K.*?(?=(?:TEMPO|\s*$))/';
$str = 'VHHH 020218Z 0202/0306 20010KT 9999 FEW015 SCT025 TX32/0206Z TX32/0306Z TN27/0222Z TEMPO 0202/0209 2500 -TSRA SHRA FEW010CB SCT015 TEMPO 0215/0221 3500 SHRA FEW015CB SCT020 TEMPO 0221/0303 2500 -TSRA SHRA FEW010CB SCT015 TEMPO 0303/0306 3500 SHRA FEW015CB SCT020=';
$result=[];
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
foreach ($matches as $mg) 
    array_push($result,$mg[0]);

print_r($result);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

And just because I can, I will add another answer that will solve the next question OP will have.

"How to make a regex for handle both TEMPO, BECMG, PROBxx, and FM?"

Again... Regex is not the tool.
Here is one example how to split a TAF in to it's "parts". Depending on airport and country some may be used and some may not be used.

I created a "fake" TAF just to prove my point.

```
$delimiters = array("TEMPO","BECMG", "PROB", "FM");
$TAF = "VHHH 020218Z 0202/0306 20010KT 9999 FEW015 SCT025 TX32/0206Z TX32/0306Z TN27/0222Z TEMPO 0202/0209 2500 -TSRA SHRA FEW010CB SCT015 TEMPO 0215/0221 3500 SHRA FEW015CB SCT020 TEMPO 0221/0303 2500 -TSRA SHRA FEW010CB SCT015 TEMPO 0303/0306 3500 SHRA FEW015CB SCT020 PROB40 0211/0212 SHRA BKN025CB BECMG 0212/0214 25015G27KT TEMPO 0202/0209 2500 -TSRA SHRA FEW010CB SCT015 FM1430 25015G27KT OVC020 SHRA=";


foreach($delimiters as $item){
    $TAF = str_replace($item, " " . $item, $TAF);
}

$TAFparts = explode("  ", $TAF);
var_dump($TAFparts);
```

Output:

```
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  string(82) "VHHH 020218Z 0202/0306 20010KT 9999 FEW015 SCT025 TX32/0206Z TX32/0306Z TN27/0222Z"
  [1]=>
  string(47) "TEMPO 0202/0209 2500 -TSRA SHRA FEW010CB SCT015"
  [2]=>
  string(41) "TEMPO 0215/0221 3500 SHRA FEW015CB SCT020"
  [3]=>
  string(47) "TEMPO 0221/0303 2500 -TSRA SHRA FEW010CB SCT015"
  [4]=>
  string(41) "TEMPO 0303/0306 3500 SHRA FEW015CB SCT020"
  [5]=>
  string(30) "PROB40 0211/0212 SHRA BKN025CB"
  [6]=>
  string(26) "BECMG 0212/0214 25015G27KT"
  [7]=>
  string(47) "TEMPO 0202/0209 2500 -TSRA SHRA FEW010CB SCT015"
  [8]=>
  string(30) "FM1430 25015G27KT OVC020 SHRA="
}
```

https://3v4l.org/26nTv

It works by adding a space before each new "group" of TAF message.
So instead of `blabla TEMPO` I make it `blabla  TEMPO` (double space).
Then I can easily explode on double space.

Answer (score 0):

I concur with Andreas sentiment -- often questions appear on SO asking for  regex-based solutions without considering or knowing the possibility of using a non-regex method.  I would urge you to consider using a non-regex solution whenever it is not unreasonably convoluted to do so.

Furthermore, I also see questions asking for 
`preg_match_all()` to "split a string" -- most of the time, this is NOT the best function for regex-based splitting.  The php function that uses regex to split a string is `preg_split()`.

Because your delimiter is static (`TEMPO`), this question *can* and arguably *should* be solved using non-regex functions.  However, a regex solution may be your personal preference for an unspecified reason (convenience, code-brevity, future modification, etc).

These are some `preg_split()` methods:

```
$in='VHHH 020218Z 0202/0306 20010KT 9999 FEW015 SCT025 TX32/0206Z TX32/0306Z TN27/0222Z TEMPO 0202/0209 2500 -TSRA SHRA FEW010CB SCT015 TEMPO 0215/0221 3500 SHRA FEW015CB SCT020 TEMPO 0221/0303 2500 -TSRA SHRA FEW010CB SCT015 TEMPO 0303/0306 3500 SHRA FEW015CB SCT020=';
var_export(array_slice(preg_split('/ TEMPO /',$in),1));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '0202/0209 2500 -TSRA SHRA FEW010CB SCT015',
  1 => '0215/0221 3500 SHRA FEW015CB SCT020',
  2 => '0221/0303 2500 -TSRA SHRA FEW010CB SCT015',
  3 => '0303/0306 3500 SHRA FEW015CB SCT020=',
)
```

My approach will will run about 10x faster than Rizwan's `preg_match_all()` approach.

---

Andreas' sample...

```
$TAF = "VHHH 020218Z 0202/0306 20010KT 9999 FEW015 SCT025 TX32/0206Z TX32/0306Z TN27/0222Z TEMPO 0202/0209 2500 -TSRA SHRA FEW010CB SCT015 TEMPO 0215/0221 3500 SHRA FEW015CB SCT020 TEMPO 0221/0303 2500 -TSRA SHRA FEW010CB SCT015 TEMPO 0303/0306 3500 SHRA FEW015CB SCT020 PROB40 0211/0212 SHRA BKN025CB BECMG 0212/0214 25015G27KT TEMPO 0202/0209 2500 -TSRA SHRA FEW010CB SCT015 FM1430 25015G27KT OVC020 SHRA=";
$delims=['TEMPO','BECMG','PROB','FM'];
var_export(array_slice(preg_split('/ (?='.implode('|',$delims).')/',$TAF),1));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'TEMPO 0202/0209 2500 -TSRA SHRA FEW010CB SCT015',
  1 => 'TEMPO 0215/0221 3500 SHRA FEW015CB SCT020',
  2 => 'TEMPO 0221/0303 2500 -TSRA SHRA FEW010CB SCT015',
  3 => 'TEMPO 0303/0306 3500 SHRA FEW015CB SCT020',
  4 => 'PROB40 0211/0212 SHRA BKN025CB',
  5 => 'BECMG 0212/0214 25015G27KT',
  6 => 'TEMPO 0202/0209 2500 -TSRA SHRA FEW010CB SCT015',
  7 => 'FM1430 25015G27KT OVC020 SHRA=',
)
```

p.s. I don't have a webpage that deals with airport weather conditions.

Answer (score 0):

A way with preg_split:

```
$result = preg_split('~(?:\A.*?\b)?(?=TEMPO\b)\b~', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

The delimiter is the start of the string until the first TEMPO or the position of the next "TEMPO". This way you don't have to shift the first item of the result array.

Pattern details:

```
~
(?: # optional non-capturing group (useful for the first match)
    \A      # start of the string anchor
    .*? \b  # characters until a word boundary
)? 
(?=TEMPO\b) # lookahead: followed by TEMPO
\b          # a word-boundary
~
```

---

Other way with preg_match_all:

```
preg_match_all('~\bTEMPO\b[^T]*(?:\BT[^T]*|T(?!EMPO\b)[^T]*)*~', $str, $matches);

$result = $matches[0];
```

This way search extract directly substrings from "TEMPO" until the next of until the end of the string. To describe the content until the next TEMPO, it uses an unrolled pattern to be efficient:

```
[^T]*                  # all that isn't a T
(?:
    \BT [^T]*          # a T at a non-word boundary position
  |                    # OR
    T(?!EMPO\b) [^T]*  # a T not followed by EMPO and a word boundary
)*
```

This design is more efficient than `.*?\b(?=TEMPO\b|$)` *(a lazy quantifier needs more test)* or `(?:[^T]|\BT|T(?!EMPO\b))*` *(the alternation is tested to many times)*

You can also write the pattern like this:

```
~\bTEMPO\b\w*(?>\w+\w*)*?(?=TEMPO\b|$)~
```

It uses a lazy quantifier but the impact is limited since it is applied to an atomic group.

Answer (score -1):

Even if the question is taged regex, I don't find that beeing the best solution for this.

I believe a simple explode will do just fine.

https://3v4l.org/kBsT8

```
$TAF = "VHHH 020218Z 0202/0306 20010KT 9999 FEW015 SCT025 TX32/0206Z TX32/0306Z TN27/0222Z TEMPO 0202/0209 2500 -TSRA SHRA FEW010CB SCT015 TEMPO 0215/0221 3500 SHRA FEW015CB SCT020 TEMPO 0221/0303 2500 -TSRA SHRA FEW010CB SCT015 TEMPO 0303/0306 3500 SHRA FEW015CB SCT020=";

$Tempo = explode(" TEMPO ", $TAF);
array_shift($Tempo); //removes the main TAF and leaves the TEMPO
var_dump($Tempo);
```

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain? If you think I "miss" the `TEMPO` from the strings then I can say that it's not needed. OP is trying to build a METAR/TAF decoder. That is airport weather. I have a webpage that does exactly the same thing and I KNOW the word TEMPO can be left out if you know it's there. And yes my answer is not regex, but is always the questioner correct with choosing method? I don't think so. Many times has someone asked for help with X when Y is far better. So again, please explain why the downvote.

Comment: As an example. If a question is about a regex to parse HTML would you answer with a regex to parse HTML or would you suggest DOM or something else?

Comment: Thank you all for the various code . the solution $TAF = "VHHH 020218Z 0202/0306 20010KT 9999 FEW015 SCT025 TX32/0206Z TX32/0306Z TN27/0222Z TEMPO 0202/0209 2500 -TSRA SHRA FEW010CB SCT015 TEMPO 0215/0221 3500 SHRA FEW015CB SCT020 TEMPO 0221/0303 2500 -TSRA SHRA FEW010CB SCT015 TEMPO 0303/0306 3500 SHRA FEW015CB SCT020 PROB40 0211/0212 SHRA BKN025CB BECMG 0212/0214 25015G27KT TEMPO 0202/0209 2500 -TSRA SHRA FEW010CB SCT015 FM1430 25015G27KT OVC020 SHRA=";
$delims=['TEMPO','BECMG','PROB','FM'];
var_export(array_slice(preg_split('/ (?='.implode('|',$delims).')/',$TAF),1)); was best.

Comment: @Trevor why regex? Regex will only slow you down. The delimiters are static so why not use a function for static delimiters? Regex will take longer and use more memory.